# Open a SharePoint PopUpPage from PerformancePoint Scorecard

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint

The following scorecard has URL at the right side named "Details" which is a KPI Hyperlink Property.

[image: Scorecard with a hyperlink]

The KPI hyperlink property accepts only the URLs that starts with http:// and does not accept any kind of URLS.

I want to open a SharePoint Pop Up from scorecard whose URL is like `javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://birhospital/OPD.aspx');`

Unfortunately this kind of URL is not supported. I tried following approaches.

**1. Replace the URL of the KPI Property using JavaScript :**
I used a script editor web part and tried to modify the URL by using script below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("a[href='http://www.birhospital/OPD.aspx']").attr('href',"javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://www.birhospital/OPD.aspx')");

});
</script>
```

Unfortunately this did not work. This kind of scripts edit URLs in SharePoint but not the URLs inside scorecard.

Any suggestions to make this work?